# Register windows service with parameters using WIX

Tags: windows, service, parameters, wix

I want to create a windows service using WIX and set some parameters (not arguments) to the service. I refer to the parameters which appears under the  System->[X]ControlSet->[Service Name]->Parameters.
Anyone knows how can I do so?
Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10621082/wix-serviceinstall-arguments#comment13768062_10621082

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I did that by manually adding registry values I need, and it works ok:

```
<Component Id="NSSM" Guid="[MYGUID]">
  <File Id="NSSM" Name="nssm.exe" Source="nssm.exe" />
  <ServiceInstall Id="RenderSvc" Name="Render" DisplayName="Render" Type="ownProcess" Start="auto" ErrorControl="normal" />
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\Render\Parameters">
     <RegistryValue Name="AppDirectory" Value="[F_ROOT]bin" Type="expandable" />
     <RegistryValue Name="Application" Value="[F_BIN]render.exe" Type="expandable" />
     <RegistryValue Name="AppParameters" Value="" Type="expandable" />
     <RegistryKey Key="AppExit">
        <RegistryValue Value="Restart" Type="string" />
     </RegistryKey>
  </RegistryKey>
  <ServiceControl Id="RenderSvc" Name="Render" Start="install" Stop="both" />
</Component>
```

After inspecting resulting msi file in Orca I think it's creating registry values before creating a service. It would be better to do that just after creation, but it works for me, so i stopped here.

Answer (score 0):

may be this will be helpfull [ServiceInstall wix element](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix2/wix_xsd_serviceinstall.htm)

Comment: I know the ServiceInstall element but there are no paramenters to add to the service